# How do I insert SQL values into an SQL Command to create a table?

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

I'm trying to create a table in SQL from Visual Studio and I keep getting an exception that reads "'Incorrect Syntax Near '@tableName'.'" Am I using the parameter values incorrectly, I've tried using just Parameters.Add("@tableName", SQLDbType.VARCHAR) and adding the value manually, but I get the same exception.

```
public string CreateTable(string tableName)
           try
           {
               using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.connectionstring))
               {
                   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"CREATE TABLE @tableName(indicatorid INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, value REAL, date DATE, ticker VARCHAR(20))", conn);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", tableName);
                   conn.Open();
                   var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   conn.Close();
                   return "Database Initialized";
               }
           }
           catch
           {
               return"Failure Creating Test Table";
           }
```

Comment: You cannot parameterize database object identifiers (like table-names).

Comment: I see, so is there a different way to do it or do I just use an interpolated string like this: $"CREATE TABLE {tableName}...";? I've heard that opens me up to SQL Injection though...

Comment: It does. That's why you need to be careful. And use `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: Not a good practice, in spite of writing dynamic query just use stored procedure and pass the parameters from your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL for this.

- **Be careful:** you must correctly escape the table name using `QUOTENAME`
- I would advise you not to blindly catch all exceptions. Let them pass through to the calling function, which can decide how to display or log the error.
- The parameter should be `nvarchar(128)`
- Note the use of a verbatim multi-line string using `@""`

```cs
public void CreateTable(string tableName)
{
    const string query = @"
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + '(
  indicatorid INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  value REAL,
  date DATE,
  ticker VARCHAR(20)
)
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.connectionstring))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@tableName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = tableName;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use Stored procedure with parameter like

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Create_New_Table", con)) {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", tableName);
      conn.Open();
      var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      conn.Close();
      return "Database Initialized";
    }
```

Comment: So what does `sp_Create_New_Table` do then?

Comment: The dynamic query you need to write in SP